# can we set actionbar height manually in android theme.light

Tags: android

I am using "Theme.Light" theme for my android project and while setting up a navigation drawer how can i set actionbar size(height).
I used the below code and i got an error..

```
<style name="Theme.Light.ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
        <item name="actionBarSize">36dip</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

can you please reply to my problem as soon as possible and thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using AppCompat, you can set the "actionBarSize" attribute in your theme (which must inherit from Theme.AppCompat.x). You can also use a Toolbar in your layout and set its layout_height to the desired value.

Comment: Hi Mr.BladeCoder i am not using AppCompat at present and i am not going to use it in future for this application. can you please tell me for the theme 'Theme.Light' and using V4 design

Comment: If you are using the native ActionBar, the answer of Darshan Mistry is the correct one. You need to set an ActionBar style in your theme, and in that style you need to set the android:height attribute to the desired height.

Answer (score 1):

Use height attribute,for actionBarHeight

```
<item name="android:height">@dimen/bar_height</item>
```

you have to create style like this:

```
<!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

        <!-- Main theme colors -->
        <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>

        <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>

        <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
        <!--   native widgets will now be "tinted" with accent color -->
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>

        <!--Action bar style-->
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar</item>

    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.ActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar.TitleText</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar.TitleText</item>
        <item name="android:height">@dimen/bar_height</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.ActionBar.TitleText" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/bar_text_size</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/bar_text_color</item>
    </style>
```

you have to try below code :

```
<resources>   
    <style name="Theme.FixedSize" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="actionBarSize">48dip</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarSize">48dip</item> 
    </style> 
 </resources>
```

Comment: i tried this too but its not working, can you please suggest anymore

Comment: @BKumar i have to edit my answer you have to create style like above.

Comment: Sorry to ask again Mr. Dharshan, i need use android V4 design with "Theme.Light" theme. The theme which you posted requires android V7 design, if i use appcompat that demands to change all layout fields in my app...i don't want that more changes. please provide any other possibility

Comment: @BKumar, have you created custom ActionBar or use default action bar?

Comment: i used the below code.. getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_title, null);
params = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
  titleTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.mytext);
  btn1 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.switch_btn1);
  btn1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  titleTextView.setText(this.getTitle());
  titleTextView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
  v.setLayoutParams(params);
  this.getActionBar().setCustomView(v);

Comment: you have to try above latest code that i edit in my answer may be it worked